# Are the RTX2080 available in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, gpu, nvidia

I have seen many posts talking that they have used the RTX2080 in AI applications.
But I am curious why do those GPUs are not available in the cloud? At least in Google Cloud, it seems that only Tesla is available (K80, V100, T4, etc).

Has anyone used an RTX2080 GPU in the cloud? Which provider?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has a table that lists which GPUs are available on each cloud:

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/gpu-cloud-computing/

This page describes the data centre GPUs:

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/data-center-gpus/

From this I think: i) only data centre GPUs are available in the cloud, and ii) RTX2020 isn't a data centre GPU, so isn't available.